# err #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_posts' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change posts using MySql Quariy and keep getting the 1093 Err 
I have tried all the tips about using a sub queries with no success

maybe somebody can help me out

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content  = CONCAT(post_content , 'testext_bla_bla')
WHERE wp_posts.id in (select wp_posts.ID
from wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_excerpt like '%LO1185LH%' and wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 27)
```

and keep getting the "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_posts' for update in FROM clause "

thanks
asaf

Answer (score 0):

Use a `alias` for you updated table;)

```
UPDATE wp_posts t1 SET t1.post_content = CONCAT(t1.post_content, 'testext_bla_bla')
WHERE t1.id IN (
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%LO1185LH%' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 27)
```

Or you can just use `LEFT JOIN` to do this;)

```
UPDATE wp_posts t1
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON t1.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
SET t1.post_content = CONCAT(t1.post_content, 'testext_bla_bla')
WHERE t1.post_excerpt LIKE '%LO1185LH%' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 27
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the update sentences don't have FROM, because you set the table to update after UPDATE clause, like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column = some_value.
```

database engine is taking the FROM clause as it's inside UPDATE sentence (because it's an update sentence) the easiest way to handle it is to make a SELECT first (with php) and use this result to handle it on update, like:

```
$result = connection()->query("SELECT blah_blah_blah");
connection()->close();
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//ok you got the result on $rs, if you wanna do an update with this it should
//be unique result, if you want to do it recursively, simply act over $rs[$i];
//then, once or in a loop: 
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column = ".$rs['index_that_you_want'].";";
connection()->query($sql);
```

(remember to take the next row using $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result); at the bottom of a loop if you need to run it recursively.